# js & jQuery not being enabled with CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, html-editor

I have been developed a webpage which enables drag & drop feature to elements using js & jQuery functions. It's working perfectly. Now i used CKEditor and integrated with this web page but i am unable to drag & drop the elements, Why ?

***simple page***: It works and i can drag & drop the elements

```
<html> <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.all.css"/>

 <script src=jquery.js"> </script>
 <script src="jquery_Drag_Drop.js"> </script>

<head> <body>
 <div id="main_div_of_the_page">
  <div id="element_1">
     <input type="button" class="manage_to_all_properties_src"/>
  </div>

  <div id="element_2">
     <input type="button" class="manage_to_all_properties_src"/>
  </div>
 </div>
</body> </html>
```

Now i am Integrating this page with CKEditor, (Drag & drop is not working, Why? )

```
<html> <head>
     <script src=ckeditor.js"> </script>

     <script src=jquery.js"> </script>
     <script src="jquery_Drag_Drop.js"> </script>

     <script type = "text/javascript">
           window.onload = function()  {

               CKEDITOR.replace( 'main_div_of_the_page'  );  
                          }   </script>

    <head> <body>
      <div id="main_div_of_the_page">
           // Same innerHTML as above    
      </div>
    </body> </html>
```

Now i modified the `config.js` of CKEditor

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
   {
config.contentsCss = 'jquery.ui.all.csss';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is disabled while editing a content in CKEditor, but you should be able to drag&drop the elements unless you are using a webkit browser.

Drag & drop while editing is a feature provided by the brower and hopefuly one day the webkit browsers will get it.

Comment: Thanks AlfonsoML, I didn't have idea about it while i was thinking differently e.g. why not invoking the event even after downloading the js files. Anyway you cleared my doubt. Thank you so much.